# Local Host JSON file isn't being read

Tags: javascript, html, json, localhost

I am trying to pass data from a local host JSON file. However, it doesn't work. Nothing prints when the button Get JSON data is pressed. Why might that be so?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("localhost:8001/count", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to perform some basic debugging. First check the network tab and ensure your file is found. Then add a breakpoint and inspect result to ensure it has the format you expect.

Comment: How could we know? How are you serving it? What's the network console say? We're not magicians. (Well a few of us are but that's not particularly useful here.)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `http://` like this `$.getJSON("http://localhost:8001/count", function(result){`

it's working for me

Comment: Does it *not* work without it, assuming your URLs make sense? Because it shouldn't be *necessary*, which can be verified by looking in your network console, making this somewhat cargo-culty.